# How does one perform asp.net mvc 4 model binding for enums?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Has the asp.net mvc team implemented a default model binding for enums? One that is out of the box and there is no need of creating a custom model binder for enums.

UPDATE:
Let's say I have an action that will be receiving a view model and a JSON object will be posted to the action.

```
jsObj{id:2, name:'mike', personType: 1}
```

and the view model:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public PersonType personType{get;set;}
}

public enum PersonType : int
{
   Good = 1,
   Bad = 2,
   Evil = 3
}
```

Will the person type be bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was there even with earlier versions. This html and `Gender = Male` form value is correctly binding to `Gender` enum property.

```
<select id="Gender" name="Gender">
     <option value="Male">Male</option>
     <option value="Female">Femal</option>
</select>
```

For the server side I find it easiest to use select lists in my view model

```
public class User
{
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserTypesSelectList { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        UserTypesSelectList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(UserType)).Select(name => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = name,
            Value = MakeEnumMoreUserFriendly(name)
        });
    }
}

public enum UserType
{
    First,
    Second
}
```

And in view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserType, Model.UserTypesSelectList)
```

Comment: tnks! but i was more interested in how it works with json objects

Comment: Im very courious why you hadn't just tried it :). It works with json same as with ordinal form posts. Read more about value providers http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt8-value-providers.html

Comment: Binding to an enum from a json object doesn't work for me in MVC3.  Not not sure we are not doing something goofy though.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out that `public UserType UserType { get; set; }` needs to be property. It won't be able to be bound back from view to an enum if it's defined as a field `public UserType UserType;`