# Passing enum value to controller. from model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, model

In my controller for Ggender it says I cannot implicitly convert type 'String', please advice.

My model:

```
public class StaffRegistrationViewModel : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your gender.")]
        public Gender? GGender
        { get; set; } //= null;

        public enum Gender
        {
            [Display(Name = "Male", Order = 0)]
            Male = 0,

            [Display(Name = "Female", Order = 1)]
            Female = 1

        }
```

My view:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!--<i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GGender, "Choose your gender:", new { @style = "", @class = "", id = "" })
            <span style="color: red;">*</span>
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Profession, new SelectList(Model.Professions, "Id", "Name"), new { placeholder = "", @style = "", @class = "form-control", id = "Profession" })*@
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.GGender, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })


            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GGender)
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
StaffRegistrationViewModel StaffRegistrationViewModel = new StaffRegistrationViewModel();

StaffRegistrationViewModel.GGender = HttpContext.Request.Form["GGender"].ToString(); //cannot implicitly convert type 'String'
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Request.Form["GGender"]` - Everything in that is a string.  And, as the error states, you can't implicitly convert a string to a `Gender`.  But you *can* use the MVC model binding in your controller action and let the framework convert it for you.  Why are you directly accessing the `Request.Form` collection in the first place?

Comment: @David was following a tutorial mate, what do you recommend to use?

Comment: Unless there's context missing here, you were following the wrong tutorial.  Start with some of the tutorials and examples on the vendor's website: https://www.asp.net/learn  Basically your controller action should accept as a parameter a model which corresponds to what the view's form is posting to that action.  The framework will automatically build the instance of that model, including type checking and validation.  You shouldn't have to work directly with `HttpContext` pretty much ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a string variable to hold `Request.Form` content & use it in a switch statement instead of directly assigning string value to enum variable:

```
string gender = HttpContext.Request.Form["GGender"].ToString();

switch (gender)
{
    case "Male":
        StaffRegistrationViewModel.GGender = Gender.Male;
        break;

    case "Female":
        StaffRegistrationViewModel.GGender = Gender.Female;
        break;

    // you can default to null value for nullable enum properties if you want
    default:
        StaffRegistrationViewModel.GGender = null;
        break;
}
```

Note that `HttpContext.Request.Form` stores submitted values as string, so that if you want to return enum values directly just use viewmodel name in controller action method to pass submitted value (and use model directive in view page e.g. `@model StaffRegistrationViewModel`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StaffRegistration(StaffRegistrationViewModel model)
{
    // other logic here

    // enum assignment example
    Gender? gender = model.GGender;

    // other logic here

    return View(model);
}
```

NB: You can write custom model binder for enums binding with `DropDownListFor`, as given in this reference: [How does one perform asp.net mvc 4 model binding for enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030052/how-does-one-perform-asp-net-mvc-4-model-binding-for-enums).